# if you really, absolutely must

Tags: ellipsis

In the following sentence, "must" has no following verb. This kind of ellipsis seems strange to me, as the omitted verb is expected to be in the sentence. Is this use common, or restricted to certain constructions?

> It has also become clear to me, from discussion of this issue in online editorial forums—or fora, if you really, absolutely **must**—that some people interpret the "it" as the object of the verb "suffice."

Comment: I think people can omit, if need(s) be, the main verb after auxiliaries: A: You must go there right away. B: Should I? A: Yes, you should.

Comment: Your example is quite different. The "should" actually implies the main verb phrase "go there right away."

Comment: 'must' is an auxiliary verb. The principle is the same. A: If you must, you can. The context transmits information.

Comment: Do you really understand the issue at all? If an auxiliary is not followed by a verb, that verb must be somewhere in the context. But in the present situation, there is no such verb.

Comment: Here's the wider context: https://jeremybutterfield.wordpress.com/2016/07/01/suffice-it-to-say-or-suffice-to-say-2/   See if you can find out the missing verb.

Comment: The only context based on the presented sentence looks like: if you must use the 'fora', the plural form of 'forum' instead of using 'forums'.

Comment: Where is the verb "use" then?

Comment: Your premise is like: There must be "a verb" in the context. My premise is like: No, it's not necessarily needed. It doesn't matter whether the main verb appears or not.

Comment: The issue, if restated in explicit terms, is whether an auxiliary can be used without a verb explicitly mentioned in the context.

Comment: Could you provide examples from legitimate sources?

Comment: There are a couple of examples like "You shouldn't have (used when receving a gift). But such examples are fixed expressions.

Comment: "Must" doesn't need a complement. Auxiliary verbs are defined as those that have the NICE properties. The 'C' stands for Code, which means that such clauses can only be understood from some key provided by the preceding context. In your example it's a little vague, but we could interpret "must" as roughly "must call it that" / "must insist on calling it" / "must be so picky" -- or something similar.

Comment: Is this dialogue okay? __A: Here's 20 dollars for your work.
B: That's not enough. A: OK, I'll give 50, if you must.__

Answer (score 3):

The implied clause after *must* can be expressed approximately:
If you must [insist on using "fora", the latinate plural of "forums"].

In other words, if you must be that pedantic.

*Really, absolutely* is double intensification of *must*; that is, if there is no other option.

Comment: Is that kind of verb omission considered sloppy?

Comment: No. For one thing, it's dialogue, and both parties know what is being referred to. It just a slightly more intense expression of "...or ,if you prefer, fora".

Comment: It's not a dialogue, but part of an essay.

Comment: Any similar examples from legitimate sources?

Comment: @Apollyon  It is not necessarily sloppy, sometimes not at all.  Yes, there are similar examples.  Give me a moment.

Comment: @Apollyon Even as part of an essay, it addresses the reader as "you", so there is an aspect of dialogue.

Comment: Could you explain why "if you must" sounds odd in " A: Here's 20 dollars for your work. B: That's not enough. A: OK, I'll give you 50, **if you must**"?

Comment: @Apollyon The exact word needed there is "insist"; there's no reason to use an auxiliary in its place.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Yes, I'd use "insist" as well. But I'm wondering why "if you must" is okay int the quoted sentence but no in the dialogue. I'm seeking a uniform explanation.

Comment: @Apollyon I'd have used "insist" in the quote in your OP as well. The writer there is speaking informally, almost chatting with the reader. The OP quote is written to be understood by educated readers. The example you've created here between A and B doesn't seem the right place for any rhetorical flourish, so I agree it sounds odd there.

Comment: The rhetorical flourish is what needs addressing here. What is it about it that allows "if you must" to be used without an explicitly mentioned verb phrase it can be linked to?

Comment: @Apollyon It's a compact context, all in a six-word parenthetical phrase with no syntactic link to the the rest of the sentence, that makes the sense instantly apparent to native readers.

Comment: Does it have the feel of a speaker stopping midsentence?

Comment: @Apollyon If I read it aloud, there would be pauses at the long dashes.

Comment: Is it okay to use "if you must" in "I sold everything and moved to Canada with John because I loved him, or I thought I loved him, if you must"?

Comment: @Apollyon Only if you really, absolutely must.

Answer (score 1):

**It is restricted to certain constructions.**

You can go if you absolutely must.                  (conditional)

Try as he might, he failed.                         (idiomatic)

If I could, I would tell you.  But I can't, so I won't.  (yes/no; conditional)

If I could go home, I would.                        (conditional)

How dare you lie to me!  I knew you would!          (ellipsis)

Can you swim?  --Yes, I can.                        (yes/no short form)

I would like to say something, if I may.            (formal; a polite expression)

If I may, could you please repeat that?             (formal; a polite expression)

Please help us if you can.                          (conditional)

Can I go home now? --No, you can not!               (yes/no short form; emphatic)

Comment: Actually, except for the "if I may, could you . .. " sentence, all of your examples are ordinary, in the sense that the auxiliaries have antecedent verb phrases. For example, "You can go if you absolutely must" means "You can go if you absolutely must (go)."  "If I could, I would tell you. But I can't, so I won't" means "If I could (tell you), I would tell you. But I can't (tell you), so I won't (tell you)."

Comment: But thanks for the "If I may, could you please repeat that?" example.

Comment: Sure.  The similarities are evident.

Comment: "Try as he might" is also interesting because it is idiomatic.  There is also "try as you may."

Comment: What is understood and omitted in "If I may, could you please repeat that"? If I may ask a favor?

Comment: If I may (interrupt you), could you please repeat that?      --formal; polite expression